# is fortify software compatible with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, fortify

I am using fortify software v3.20 and it doesn't seem to be compatible with VS 2012.

Is the latest version working with VS 2012 if so which one?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably if you ask to HP, they may be able to help you better.

Comment: 3.7 does not include 2012, it includes 2010 and under.  This information is pretty hard to find on the manufacturers website.  They also have no public roadmap (that I can find).

Answer (score 2):

3.8 is now available and supports VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

The next release of Fortify SCA (v3.7?) should have VS2012 support.

Answer (score 0):

Fortify 3.7 doesn't support VS .Net Release 2012. It supports VS .Net Releases 2003/5/8/10.

Answer (score 0):

SCA 3.7 with its auditing and scanning plugins supports the VS 2003, 2005, 2008 and 2010. No express editions!